# android NDK debugging in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-ndk

I am using ndk 12b or ndk 10d
I want to debug .so file in eclipse.
But I have a problem.
I tried to debug .so using android native application in "DEBUG AS".
But I received this result from console.

"gdbserver output: run-as: exec failed for lib/gdbserver Error:No such file or directory"

I set my android.mk and application.mk like this.

```
LOCAL_MODULE    := test
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -landroid

APP_STL:=stlport_static
APP_OPTIM:=debug
APP_ABI := all
APP_CFLAGS  += -Wno-error=format-security
LOCAL_LDFLAGS   += --no-warn-shared-textrel
```

I also set NDK_DEBUG=1 as build option.
what should I do solve it?

Comment: Is your project c++ or Android Native Project?

Comment: Maybe it's Android Native Project. I created Android Project and just add native support.